# jira-python invalid syntax

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

First time using jira-python, and I get this error when I run just a simple initialization.

```
from jira.client import JIRA

jira = JIRA()
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 146   
if re.search(u"^User '(.*)' was not found in the system\.", error, re.U):   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas? I am running this with py32

Comment: Which `jira-python` version are you using?

Comment: jira-0.21 , installed using "pip install jira"

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like a bug.

They are [claiming python 3 support](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#dependencies), but there are `u` strings in the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/bspeakmon/jira-python/src/64de4eab1f831cbb66c68444bde50b6b8e1bfeda/jira/resources.py?at=master#cl-143). Python 3 doesn't support `u` strings, all of the strings are `unicode`.

Consider submitting an issue to the `python-jira` [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/bspeakmon/jira-python/issues?status=new&status=open).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already installed Jira in your CMD, like:

```
$ pip install jira
```

Then just try something like the following:

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com') #Project URL

issue = jira.issue('KEY-1')
print issue.fields.project.key            # 'KEY'
print issue.fields.summary                # 'Issue Summary'
```